# Algorithm for determine the Arc Mid Point

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I am currently looking to implement an algorithm that will be able to compute the arc midpoint. From here on out, I will be referring to the diagram below. What is known are the start and end nodes (A and B respectively), the center (point C) and point P which is the intersection point of the line AB and CM (I am able to find this point without knowing point M because line AB is perpendicular to line CM and thus, the slope is -1/m). I also know the arc angle and the radius of the arc. I am looking to find point M.

I have been looking at different sources. Some suggest converting coordinates to polar, computing the mid point from the polar coordinates then reverting back to Cartesian. This involves sin and cos (and arctan) which I am a little reluctant to do since trig functions take computing time.

I have been looking to directly computing point M by treating the arc as a circle and having Line CP as a line that intersects the circle at Point M. I would then get two values and the value closest to point P would be the correct intersection point. However, this method, the algebra becomes long and complex. Then I would need to create special cases for when P = C and for when the line AB is horizontal and vertical. This method is ok but I am wondering if there are any better methods out there that can compute this point that are simpler?

Also, as a side note, I will be creating this algorithm in C++.

[image: Arc Features]

Comment: Do you know about https://math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the place

Comment: You know vector CP and want to renormalize it to give it the same length as CA? Btw P is just the midpoint of AB.

Comment: This is a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: Seems like the vector `CM` is just the vector `CP` with it's length equal to the arc radius. `CM = CP / |CP| * [arch radius]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A circumference in polar form is expressed by

```
x = Cx + R cos(alpha)
y = Cy + R sin(alpha)
```

Where `alpha` is the angle from center `C` to point `x,y`. The goal now is how to get `alpha` without trigonometry.

The arc-midpoint `M`, the point `S` in the middle of the segment `AB`, and your already-calculated point `P`, all of them have the same `alpha`, they are on the same line from `C`.

Let's get vector `vx,vy` as `C` to `S`. Also calculate its length:

```
vx = Sx - Cx = (Ax + Bx)/2 - Cx
vy = Sy - Cy = (Ay + By)/2 - Cy
leV = sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy)
```

I prefer `S` to `P` because we can avoid some issues like infinite CP slope or sign to apply to slope (towards M or its inverse).

By defintions of *sin* and *cos* we know that:

```
sin(alpha) = vy / leV
cos(alpha) = vx / leV
```

and finally we get

```
Mx = Cx + R * vx / leV
My = Cy + R * vy / leV
```

**Note**: To calculate `R`you need another `sqrt` function, which is not quick, but it's faster than sin or cos.

For better accuracy use the average of `Ra= dist(AC)` and `Rb= dist(BC)`

Comment: So the R here, is that the radius? If so, that is a known parameter

Comment: @philm Yes, R= radius. I added the note for the case you have only points (A, B, Center)

Comment: Cool thanks, So the point S in your description, is sounds like that this is point P in my diagram. If so, then this is another known parameter.

Comment: S != P    S is on AB segment and on CM segment. P is on CM, but may be not on AB. My solution works well with S, I don't know if it will also do with P. Read the line *"I prefer..."*

Comment: Point P has to be on line segment AB and CM because point P is the intersection point of line segment AB and CM which are perpendicular to each other. Either way, I will attempt both methods (when S = P and S != P) and see if it matters. But I do like this algorithm

Comment: OK, I verified that this algorithm is working! Thank you very much! This made things way simpler! Also, I coded it such that P = S and it works out fine. I also had to create some special cases for when P = C and if the slope of line AB = 0 and INF. Other then that, everything is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

> I would then get two values

This is algebraically unavoidable.

> and the value closest to point P would be the correct intersection point.

Only if the arc covers less than 180°.

> Then I would need to create special cases for when P = C

This is indeed the most tricky case. If *A, B, C* lie on a line, you don't know which arc is the arc, and won't be able to answer the question. Unless you have some additional information to start with, e.g. know that the arc goes from *A* to *B* in a counter-clockwise direction. In this case, you know the orientation of the triangle *ABM* and can use that to decide which solition to pick, instead of using the distance.

> and for when the line AB is horizontal and vertical

Express a line as *ax + by + c = 0* and you can treat all slopes the same. THese are homogeneous coordinates of the line, you can compute them e.g. using the cross product *(a, b, c) = (Ax, Ay, 1) × (Bx, By, 1)*. But more detailed questions on how best to compute these lines or intersect it with the circle should probably go to the Math Stack Exchange.

> if there are any better methods out there that can compute this point that are simpler?

Projective geometry and homogeneous coordinates can avoid a lot of nasty corner cases, like circles of infinite radius (also known as lines) or the intersection of parallel lines. But the problem of deciding between two solutions remains, so it probably doesn't make things as simple as you'd like them to be.